# Fade-In effect for new items of ListView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, animation, uwp

I would like that whenever a new item is added to a ListView, is shows up with a fade in effect (Opacity 0 => 1)

For now, I have applied a `Transition` to the inner `Panel` to make new elements come from below with a nice animation:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView">
            <ItemsStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition
                        FromVerticalOffset="400" />
                </TransitionCollection>
            </ItemsStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        </ItemsStackPanel>

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Can I do something similar to the Fade In effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like that whenever a new item is added to a ListView, is shows up with a fade in effect (Opacity 0 => 1)

If you want to animate one item when it is added, actually by testing on my side, when adding a new item, it shows up with fade in effect by default. The `ItemContainerTransitions` of the default [`ListView styles and templates`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299137.aspx) contains [`Add​Delete​Theme​Transition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.adddeletethemetransition), so when you adding or deleting item from the `ListView` it has default animation to animate item in and out of view.

[image]

If you want to animate the `ItemsStackPanel` to make the Opacity from 0 to 1, you may use the [`Double​Animation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation). Code as follows:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <ItemsStackPanel
           x:Name="stack"
           ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
           Opacity="0">
           <ItemsStackPanel.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger>
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                           <DoubleAnimation
                               Storyboard.TargetName="stack"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="1"
                               Duration="0:0:5" />
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
           </ItemsStackPanel.Triggers>
       </ItemsStackPanel>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

If you don't want the default fade in effect defined by `ItemContainerTransitions`, you may add the storyboard as you want to the elements inside the `ItemTemplate`, for example:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Category">
       <StackPanel x:Name="stack" Opacity="0">
           <StackPanel.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger>
                   <BeginStoryboard>
                       <Storyboard>
                           <DoubleAnimation
                               Storyboard.TargetName="stack"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                               To="1"
                               Duration="0:0:5" />
                       </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
           </StackPanel.Triggers>
           <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```